# How to close UI when user is replying/forwarding in inline mode

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When user is replying/forwarding in popup, Office-js exposes a function to close current form:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.close();
```

Even official documentation on this function says that close() does nothing in inline mode [Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.3/office.context.mailbox.item).

What should we use when reply/forward is in inline mode and that we want to close it?

Comment: Closing in inline mode isn't supported. Can you help us understand the scenarios you are trying to solve with that function?

Comment: New feature suggestions can be made at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins